# Get access through another Entity in Doctrine2

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have the problem with Association in Doctrine2.

My Entity mapping is:
Brand:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Entity
     */
    class Brand
    {
        /**
         * @ORM\Id
         */
        protected $id;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string")
         */
        protected $name;

        /**
         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Model", mappedBy="brand")
         */
        protected $models;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
         */
        protected $isPopular;
    }
```

Model:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Entity
     */
    class Model
    {
        /**
         * @ORM\Id
         */
        protected $id;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string")
         */
        protected $name;

        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\VehicleType", inversedBy="models")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="vehicle_type_id", referencedColumnName="id")
         */
        protected $vehicleType;

        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Brand", inversedBy="models")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="brand_id", referencedColumnName="id")
         */
        protected $brand;
    }
```

VehicleType:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Entity
     */
    class VehicleType
    {
        /**
         * @ORM\Id
         */
        protected $id;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string")
         */
        protected $name;

        /**
         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Model", mappedBy="vehicleType")
         */
        protected $models;
    }
```

How I can get in Entity VehicleType array of popular Brands (brand.isPopular = true)?
Мay be my mapping is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I can do like this

```
$vehicleTypes = $this->getEm()->getRepository('AppBundle:VehicleType')->findAll();

    foreach ($vehicleTypes as $vehicleType) {
        print ('<p>'.$vehicleType->getName().'</p>');
        $brands = $this->getQb()
            ->select('brand')
            ->from('AppBundle:Brand', 'brand')
                ->join('brand.models', 'models')
            ->where('brand.isPopular = true')
                ->andWhere('models.vehicleType = :vehicleType')
            ->setParameter('vehicleType', $vehicleType)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
        ;
        foreach ($brands as $brand) {
            print('<p> - '.$brand->getNameEng().'</p>');
        }
    }
```

But I have n+1 querys to DB, where n size of  VehicleType. Posible decrise DB querys?